# Null Sinks are created without Monitors

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio

`pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=nsink`
creates a null sink named `nsink`, which is visible in pavucontrol and can have streams assigned to it.
Normally, this would also create `nsink.monitor`, but since a recent update the `nsink.monitor` does not exist anymore. Trying to remap `nsink.monitor` returns `Failure: No such entity` and the monitor does not appear in pavucontrol.

I have no idea where to start troubleshooting this, but I would like to force the creation of a monitor attached to the null sink.

Comment: Bisect the pulseaudio version: checkout the repository, build it yourself, find the commit where it stops working. Or, if your admin skills are not up to that, file a bug on the pulseaudio bug tracker.